# In Plaid, is it possible to get a webhook notification when credentials expire or become invalid?

Tags: webhooks, plaid

Use Case: A user has supplied Plaid with credentials to "amex". For some reason, that user changes their password. Plaid can no longer access Amex on behalf of the user.

Problem: I believe that right now, the information flow for bad credentials is that an error message is received when the Plaid client checks for updated information (e.g. new transactions). However, Plaid probably knows about the incorrect credentials prior to that request. Relying on a synchronous event (requesting new transactions from the PlaidAPI, e.g.) to communicate the error potentially leaves Plaid customers in a bad state.

It would be nice to see something like

```
"code"=>"49","message"=>"Credentials Invalid","access_token"=>"XYZAAAA"
```

Answer (score 2):

Great point - we have been working on more far reaching webhooks for situations where credentials have changed, accounts are locked, etc. I'll keep you posted as we add this functionality.

In the meantime, you are now able to use the PATCH endpoint to update credentials for existing users. Check it out in the docs here: https://plaid.com/docs#Docs_Update_Credentials

Thanks again for the input and let me know if you have any other questions!

Carl